# Export from Xpages view to Excel and keep grid lines

Tags: excel, xpages

I have a button that exports a view to Excel from an Xpage. It works fairly well, but when the user opens up Excel there are no grid lines and I know they are going to freak out. I have looked for an hour on the internet for how to turn these one but I can't find how.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is my code"

```
    var output:string = "";
    for(i=0;i < sessionScope.searchDocIDArray.length; i++)
    {
    var docId=sessionScope.searchDocIDArray[i];
    var doc=database.getDocumentByID(docId);

    output += "<tr>";
    output += "<td>" + doc.getItemValueString("user") + "</td>";
    output += "<td>" + doc.getItemValueString("loc") + "</td>";
    output += "<td>" + doc.getItemValueString("date") + "</td>";
    output += "<td>" + doc.getItemValueString("workCategory") + "</td>";
    output += "<td>" + doc.getItemValueString("state") + "</td>";
    output += "<td>" + doc.getItemValueString("timeSpent") + "</td>";
    output += "<td>" + doc.getItemValueString("notes") + "</td>";

    output += "</tr>";
    }

    facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse().setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=TSC Time Spent.xlxs");
    facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse().setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

    facesContext.getResponseWriter().write("<x:WorksheetOptions>")
    facesContext.getResponseWriter().write("<x:Panes>");
    facesContext.getResponseWriter().write("</x:Panes>");
    facesContext.getResponseWriter().write("<x:WorksheetOptions>")

    facesContext.getResponseWriter().write("<table><thead><tr><td><b>User</b></td><td><b>Loc</b></td><td><b>Date</b></td><td><b>Work Category</b></td><td><b>Time Spent</b></td><td><b>Notes</tr></thead>"+output+"</table>");
    facesContext.getResponseWriter().endDocument();
```

Comment: You are not closing the <x:WorksheetOptions> element if that matters

Comment: I got really excited when I saw that, but unfortunately I changed it and it didn't work. I *really* want to find a way for this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make sure grid lines are intact is to export to csv instead of using html tags to write out your content.

You also can assign css to your to td elements but the borders will not look like they do natively in excel.

Here is an example of using csv.  This is a simplified version of something I used in afterRenderResponse:

```
var exCon = facesContext.getExternalContext();
var writer = facesContext.getResponseWriter();
var response = exCon.getResponse();
var output = "";
var colHeaders = "col1,col2,col3,col4,col5";
// Loop through data set
while (doc != null) {

output+="\"" + val1 + "\",";
output+="\"" + val2 + "\",";
output+="\"" + val3 + "\",";
output+="\"" + val4 + "\",";
output+="\"" + val5 + "\",";
output += @Char(13)+@Char(10);  // start a new row
}
response.setContentType("application/csv-tab-delimited-table;charset=utf-8");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=actionExport.csv");
writer.write(colHeaders+@Char(13)+@Char(10)); // Add the first row as column titles and add line feed
writer.write(output+@Char(13)+@Char(10));  //
writer.endDocument();
```

Comment: I may want to go this way, as I have another problem. This method does not always work from within the client. Some problem with the ReDirect I think. Do you have any link to some examples of this to get me started.

Comment: I am trying to get this to work, but ran into a problem. I am putting the code directly in the button, not opening up another document. I don't think that I can do this all in the button now. So I moved this code to an Xpage that I try to open from my button in the Xpage. But on the client it sometimes opens the page and sometimes it does't. I have another question open about this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688898/xpages-contet-redirecttopage-only-works-intermitently-in-notes-client).

Answer (score 1):

It's going to take a bit more investigation, but I would recommend looking at using Apache POI for writing to Excel. It won't throw security alerts with Excel 2007+ like the table approach does. It has more specific APIs for setting styling. The HSSF classes are the ones you want (standing for Horrible SpreadSheet Format!).

Comment: What Paul said. Much better to export as a native file.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this :-)

```
<x:WorksheetOptions>
  <x:DisplayGridlines/>
</x:WorksheetOptions>
```

Comment: That looked pretty good, but didn't work. I tried DisplayGridlines=True and that didn't work either. When I google it is says you have to be one the active worksheet. I used to know how to get that in LS, but not in JS.