# context.redirectToPage only works intermitently in Notes Client

Tags: xpages

I have a button in an Xpage with an OnClick event that does the following:

```
    var viewPanel=getComponent("viewPanel1");
    var docIDArray=viewPanel.getSelectedIds();
    sessionScope.put("searchDocIDArray",docIDArray);
    var url="exportData.xsp";
    context.redirectToPage(url, false);
```

The exportData page is not rendered but just has some code to write out an Excel file. In the client sometimes it does this and sometimes it does nothing and sometimes it writes over the current Xpgage and is just blank. I think what I need to do is to just launch that page in a new window? I am not sure.

It works on the web every time.

Comment: Bryan, perhaps your exportData.xsp code fails on certain occasions which could be the reason for the "does nothing" and the "is just blank"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version is your client?

Another approach you can try is opening your xagent with a window.open () in the onComplete event of your button. I don't remember off the top of my head if that works in xpinc. The advantage of this is your export will open in a new tab.

Comment: My client is 9.0.1. I cannot find an onComplete event for the button. How can I debug this code to see what is happening?

Comment: The onComplete (as well as onError and onStart) for some reason are not very intuitive to locate.

To find them, click your button, switch to source, click the eventHandler tag for your button, then click the properties tab.  THEN you should be able to see these events.  They are all client side events.  Open onComplete and add your window.open(urlOfYourXAgent).

Comment: Oh yeah. .. make sure your button is doing a partial refresh and not full.

Comment: Micheal, I have code that I have used for ages for exporting to Excel (and word and so on) that is in Lotus Script. I am thinking that for the time being, until I can figure out how to do this natively, I can just call my agent. The only issue I have is I want to past what documents that user has selected in the filtered view. Is there a way to pass that in an agent context?

Comment: Personally, I think by now trying to utilize a lotusscript agent you are increasing the complexity.  I tested the scenario I outlined combined with my sample code from your other post and it worked a charm in XPiNC in 9.0.1.  If you want we can have a Skype chat to hammer this out.

Comment: That would be much appreciated. I am free a lot of this weekend. My email is bryanschmiedeler AT me.com.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53859/discussion-between-michael-g-smith-and-bryan-schmiedeler)